# integral of continuous function can be very small

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, with $f(x)$ continuous. Is the following statement true?

> $\exists M, \forall y> x\geq M$ such that $\lvert\int_{x}^{y}{f(s)ds}\rvert\leq \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: As currently written, If I pick $y = x$, then $|\int_{x}^{y}f(s)\,ds| = 0 \le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. So the statement is true. However, I suspect that you meant to have the conditionals in a different order.

Comment: @JimmyK4542. revised.

Answer (score 1):

The only way "$|\int_x^y f(s)\,ds| \le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$" can be true is if $\int_x^y f(s)\,ds = 0$.

Hence, the statement is equivalent to "$\exists M, \forall y > x \ge M, \int_x^y f(s)\,ds = 0$"

This clearly fails if we take $f(x) = 1$. Hence, the statement "$\exists M, \forall y> x\geq M$ such that $|\int_{x}^{y}{f(s)ds}|\leq \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$" is false.